# Unity: Assigning a new clip to video player changes ALL video player clips in my current scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video-player

I have several GameObjects instantiated, all of them have a video player component, all those objects are inside a main canvas and should be able to play the video simultaneously.
When I assign one of them a new clip, ALL of them start playing over again and change their resource to the new one. Of course, it should only change the one I actually assign it it.
I have made sure, the function below gets only called ONCE and on the correct object.
I also printed the hash codes of the videos player to make sure they are different objects, and they are.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this ?

How I assign the clip

```
        public virtual void SetVideoResource(string fileName)
        {
            videoName = fileName;
            textPanel.SetActive(false);
            videoPanel.SetActive(true);
            videoPlayer = videoPanel.GetComponentInChildren<VideoPlayer>();
            videoPlayer.clip = (VideoClip)Resources.Load("Videos/" + fileName);
            Debug.Log(videoPlayer.GetHashCode());
        }
```

Setup of my Video Player component

[image]

And the target texture

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by myself:

The reason for the behaviour was not, that all the clips got reassigned. (All video players still had their individual video resource)
But instead, I had one single render texture assigned to the video players. Of course that wont work, as all video players will render their frames onto this one render texture.

The solution instantiates a custom render texture based on the size of the video panel for each individual video player:

```
        public virtual void SetVideoResource(string fileName)
        {
            videoName = fileName;
            textPanel.SetActive(false);
            videoPanel.SetActive(true);
            float parentWidth = videoPanel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width;
            float parentHeight = videoPanel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height;
            videoPlayer = videoPanel.GetComponentInChildren<VideoPlayer>();
            CustomRenderTexture targetTexture = new CustomRenderTexture((int)(parentWidth*0.90f), (int)(parentHeight * 0.90f), RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
            videoPanel.GetComponentInChildren<RawImage>().texture = targetTexture;
            videoPlayer.targetTexture = targetTexture;
            videoPlayer.clip = (VideoClip)Resources.Load("Videos/" + fileName);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Video Player's TargetTexture and RawImage point to the same RenderTexture. You can create multiple render textures and assign them to each video player.

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y9iq.png)